# Pass querystring value to PARAM tag in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I've two web application lets call them **app1** and **app2**. They both are hosted on different servers.

Now from **index_app1.jsp** page of app1, I need to open **index_app2.jsp** page of app2. I need to pass some parameter to index_app2.jsp, What should be the best way (*I thought of using session, but due to different context I can't access the session value in index_app2.jsp, So I've to go with querystring*).

Now in index_app2.jsp page I'm calling one third party applet for some file manipulation. and the applet tag looks like below

```
<applet id="Applet1" name="FileApplet" width="1" height="2" > 
    <param name='inputtype' value=??? > //<---- How can I pass value in place of ??? from previous page which I got in querystring
</applet>
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: 1) What is the form of the URL that app2 is being given? The server & server path is not of interest, or even the page, just the part starting `?..`. More to the point, is the `value` included as a parameter? 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: If its a different server, then also can I use the session to retrieve the value from the main page ? Regarding plugin-free web, it's a legacy system and we've to move around it till the whole infra gets updated.

Comment: I don't see an answer to *"What is the form of the URL that app2 is being given?"*

Comment: As of now it is simple like www.example.com, now I added one parameter and it changed to www.example.com?name=test, before this it was hard coded but now I am using it as <param name="inputtype" value=<%out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>> is it fine ?

Comment: *"..is it fine ?"* You''re in a better position than anyone else to determine that. **Did it work?**

Comment: By the way, I'm guessing `value=<%out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>` should be more like `value=<%request.getParameter("name");%>`. But try it. I don't program JSP/servlets, just know they can dynamically create a page using data from the query parameters.

Comment: Yes It worked, I tried `value=<%request.getParameter("name");%>` but it renders empty, but `value=<%out.println(request.getParameter("name"));%>` works fine. Thanks for your time :)